# keycloak keep on refreshing after login

Tags: keycloak

when i locally run the keycloak, i am getting login form. Once i enter the credentials, the keycloak is rediectd to the "http://localhost:5555/auth/admin/master/console/#state=c829dac8-a26a-4bd0-8326-b4e395638cf8&session_state=71abe7bb-abba-40e9-863f-1feb8c600e24&code=7eeffe3c-a91f-4b5d-9bae-f57fee5486cc.71abe7bb-abba-40e9-863f-1feb8c600e24.35787e50-1037-4f58-b0fa-521414c30666" url. And this url is refreshed every second and i am not seeing any page on screen.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @Maria I got the exact same issue, any update about it ?

Comment: Same this is happening to me. I am also getting weird log: KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredUserSessions:.You guys are also getting this log.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is still struggling with the issue:
Try the following things:

- Delete your node-modules folder and again install it
- Ensure that  `<React.StrictMode>` in under your
  `<ReactKeycloakProvider>`
- Do not use `keycloak.login()` when you mount your component instead
  use `onLoad: "login-required",checkLoginIframe: false`

So basically in your provider you have to pass it in `init` as a props

```
 <ReactKeycloakProvider
authClient={keycloak}
initOptions={{
  onLoad: "login-required",
  checkLoginIframe: false,
}}
>
<ReactStrictMode , router etc...>
```

do not use `keycloak.login()` while you mount any component expecting that will take me to the keycloak login page! Let the `onload` handle it automatically.