# Regenerate registration access token crash keycloak infinite loop

Tags: keycloak

I've recently been using Keycloak for my Angular web app and I have encountered an error or a bug, perhaps.

I tried pressing regenerate registration access token in the master realm as in the screenshot below.
[Keycloak server client panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mcr9.png) (testing purposes)

But after that, the admin panel started crashing with constant refreshes (infinite loop) and the following error getting posted: [keycloak error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kWcE.png)

I don't know what to do. Is there a way of reseting my keycloak without losing my data / settings?
My problem is similar to this one: [keycloak keep on refreshing after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117830/keycloak-keep-on-refreshing-after-login). Sadly it does not have comments this is why I'm asking for help.

Thank you!

Update: I have tried the

```
checkLoginIframe: false
```

solution in my angular app but it is still stuck in the infinite loop

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this?